# R Shiny - Passing Youtube links to iframe

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I want to pass some Youtube embedded links on the clicks of action button, but unable to do so, I have experimented with some codes attached below, where I have tried passing the links from server to ui, can some one please help me find a solution for the below problem:

Here are some dummy codes:

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyLP)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Title"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("analyse1","Link 1"),
          actionButton("analyse2","Link 2"),
          iframe(width = "250", height = "150",url_link =s5)), #s5 in server.r are reactive youtube links 
        mainPanel(
textOuput("textOut")
          ))
    ))
```

server.r

```
shinyServer(
  function(input,output,session){

    terms1<-reactiveValues(dta = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$analyse1,{withProgress({
      setProgress(message = "Please Wait...")
      terms1$dta<-"Video 1"
      s5<-"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XQTAD9P5A1U"})})

    observeEvent(input$analyse2,{withProgress({
      setProgress(message = "Please Wait...")
      terms1$dta<-"Video 2"
      s5<-"https://www.youtube.com/embed/em1u7iO9D1k"})})

output$textOut<-renderText({
  (terms1$dta)
})

  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render the html from the server. This can be done using renderUI in the server and htmlOutput in the ui.

This simple app may help get you started:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(titlePanel("Title"),
                 mainPanel(htmlOutput("video"))),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$video <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/XQTAD9P5A1U")
    })
  }
)
```

Also, here it is with action buttons:

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Title"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    actionButton("analyse1", "Link 1"),
                    actionButton("analyse2", "Link 2")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(htmlOutput("video"))
                ))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  terms1 <- reactiveValues(link = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$analyse1, {
    terms1$link <- "https://www.youtube.com/embed/XQTAD9P5A1U"
  })

  observeEvent(input$analyse2, {
    terms1$link <- "https://www.youtube.com/embed/em1u7iO9D1k"
  })

  output$video <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src = terms1$link, width = 600, height = 400)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @NBATrends perfect, I'll incorporate these in my codes.